# Использование "что" в роли члена предложения

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Где-то это описано? Каковы правила пунктуации в этих случаях? Главное - как распознать, что "что" является членом предложения?
Например: "Он понял что натворил". Тут ведь не нужна запятая? А в "Он понял, что попался" - нужна?

Answer (score 3):

В обоих случаях запятая нужна, так как оба предложения сложноподчинённые.

В первом предложении *"Он понял, что натворил"* логическое ударение падает на союзное слово - местоиимение ЧТО, которое в предложении является дополнением.

А во втором предложении  *"Он понял, что попался"* придаточное присоединяется к главному союзом ЧТО, на который, конечно,  не падает логическое ударение и который никаким членом предложения не является.

Посмотрите здесь: [Сложноподчинённое предложение](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

Comment: Хм...
В предложении "Он понял что натворил" мне упорно не хочется ставить запятую, ведь "ЧТО" здесь главное слово, а вовсе не дополнение. "Нерон понял что натворил" - так лучше?
По каким признакам можно отличить первое предложение от второго?

Comment: >> *мне упорно не хочется ставить запятую, ведь "ЧТО" здесь главное слово, а вовсе не дополнение* Нет, дополнение. А предложение все равно сложноподчиненное, как и во втором случае. Но во втором "что" - это не дополнение.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае не так важно выучить правила пунктуации, как необходимо  понимать грамматику.

В СПП с придаточным изъяснительным основным средством связи является союзы.
**Союз ЧТО – нейтральный, основной**; другие союзы имеют дополнительные значения: союз КАК – достоверный,  союз БУДТО  – вероятностный,  союз ЧТОБЫ – модальный и т.д.

**Союзные слова** используются как исключение, если придаточная часть содержит местоименное слово (что, как, когда и др.). **Тогда это местоименное слово берет на себя функцию связи, а союз "что" опускается**.

Например: **Что** он натворил! - Он понял, **что** он натворил. Здесь "что" - **дополнение**. Союзные слова, в отличие от союзов, являются  членами предложения (подлежащим, дополнением, обстоятельством, определением).

Он понял: он попался! (бессоюзное предложение, БСП), Он понял, **что** (он) попался (СПП).
Здесь союз "что" - только служебное слово, служит для связи предложений, членом предложения не является.

В обоих случаях мы имеем СПП с одним придаточным, и, согласно правилам, запятая ставится между главной и придаточной частью.

Answer (score 0):

Описано здесь: http://www.e-reading.by/chapter.php/48854/52/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html

*ОН понял, что натворил.* Сложноподчинённое предложение с неполным придаточным (Он понял, что он натворил).

Answer (score 0):

"Он понял, что натворил" и "Он понял, что попался" - запятая нужна в обоих случаях. Если придаточное предложение со  словом "что" распространено (содержит хотя бы один второстепенный член), оно обязательно выделяется запятой.
Но вы можете проверить, является "что" союзом или союзным словом, следующим образом. Попробуйте вместо слова "что"  подставить другое как член предложения. Например, он понял, ЕРУНДУ натворил (конечно, это речевая ошибка, но теоретически слово можно подставить). Если слово можно подставить, значит ЧТО является союзным словом (относительным местоимением). Во втором предложении слово подставить НЕЛЬЗЯ, поэтому в нём ЧТО - союз